# Is there a way to visualize a block diagram of a drake system?

Tags: drake

After I construct a DiagramBuilder and connect systems via ports, I would like to see this system as a visual block diagram, sort of like simulink. Is there a way to export a png of the block diagram or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After building the DiagramBuilder into a Diagram, you can call the [System::GetGraphvizString](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_system.html#a588e4f7454694f04b4b654d154f170f3) function on the Diagram object.

There's an example in the [dynamical_systems.ipynb](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Drake-0b3b2c53-a7ad-441b-80f8-bf8350752305/project/Tutorials-2b4fc509-aef2-417d-a40d-6071dfed9199/%2Fdynamical_systems.ipynb) tutorial.